# Getting data section with maximum element

Tags: grep, sed, awk

I have some data stored in JSON-like format.

```
{
    {
        value1: 14,
        value2: 12,
        value3: 1
    },
    {
        value1: 4,
        value3: -1
    }
}
```

How can I get subsection with maximum 'value3' value using `awk` (which is most preferable and related to that kind of problems, I think), `sed` or `grep`?

So, this output is expecting:

```
{
    value1: 14,
    value2: 12,
    value3: 1
}
```

Comment: What is the number of 'levels' of curly braces?  Is it reasonably short, or can it be arbitrarily long?

Comment: Number of 'levels' is constant and equal 2 like in example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing the formatting is always as in example – one value or section delimiter per line:

```
awk '/\{/{s="";i=1}i{s=s"\n"$0}$1=="value3:"{v=$2}/\}/{if(V==""||V<v){V=v;S=s}i=0}END{print S}' json-like.file
```

An `RS`-based alternative, in case not getting the section delimiters is acceptable:

```
awk -vRS='}' '{sub(/.*\{/,"")}match($0,/value3: (\S+)/,m)&&(v==""||v<m[1]){v=m[1];s=$0}END{print s}' json-like.file
```

An `RT`-based alternative:

```
awk -vRS='\\{[^{}]+\\}' 'match(RT,/value3: (\S+)/,m)&&(v==""||v<m[1]){v=m[1];s=RT}END{print s}' json-like.file
```

**Explanations** as requested in comment.

```
awk '
/\{/{s="";i=1}   # start of section? reset accumulated section data; set inside section flag
i{s=s"\n"$0}   # inside section? append current record to the accumulated data
$1=="value3:"{v=$2}   # value3 entry? store its value
/\}/{if(V==""||V<v){V=v;S=s}i=0}   # end of section? if no previous max or previous max value less than current value then set maxvalue to value and max section to section; reset inside section flag
END{print S}   # output max section
' json-like.file

awk -vRS='}' '   # record separator is the end of section delimiter
{sub(/.*\{/,"")}   # remove start of section delimiter and anything before it
match($0,/value3: (\S+)/,m)&&(v==""||v<m[1]){v=m[1];s=$0}   # current record contains value3 entry and no previous max or previous max value is less than its value? set max value to value and section to current record
END{print s}   # output section
' json-like.file

awk -vRS='\\{[^{}]+\\}' '   # record separator is an entire section
match(RT,/value3: (\S+)/,m)&&(v==""||v<m[1]){v=m[1];s=RT}   # current record terminator contains value3 entry and no previous max or previous max value is less than its value? set max value to value and section to current record terminator
END{print s}   # output section
' json-like.file
```

Comment: Nicely done! If you get a chance can you add some explanation as to what awk is doing for learning purposes.

Comment: I found a bug. What if all the values will be negative? You need to initialize V as -INFINITY or something.

Comment: Indeed. But that as no actual _-infinity_ is supported in `awk`, that would be just a special value needing special treatment. V and v are already initialized with a special value: the empty string. Added the special treatment part to all of them.